# IF && Statement Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope someone can assist me with this issue. I literally don't know how to do it. I don't know which function to use in javascript.

I have a form which is named: **"request-a-load"**

This form has 10 locations which can be chosen from a drop-down. This one is: "Loading Places".

It also has a drop-down to choose a "Truck Size": Small; Medium; Heavy.

The last drop-down is "Container Size" with 2 values: "20' Container; 40' Container".

Of the 10 loading places which can be chosen, there are 3 which will never use "Small" or "Medium" sized trucks. These 3 values for "Loading Place" are: "London; Manchester; Liverpool;" (Just an example)

**This is what needs to happen:**

Show **"Container Size"** as **"20' Container"** if *"Loading Place"* is NOT "London","Manchester","Liverpool" AND **"Truck Size"** is **"Small"** OR **"Medium"**

**It must also:**

Show **"Container Size"** as **"40' Container"** if *"Loading Place"* is NOT "London","Manchester","Liverpool" AND **"Truck Size"** is **"Heavy"**.

My bad code:

```js
$("div.trucksize").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "Small - 5 tons") {
                    $("div.containersize").val("20' Container");
                }
                if ($(this).val() == "Medium - 10 tons") {
                    $("div.containersize").val("20' Container");
                }
                  
                if ($(this).val() == "Heavy - 24 tons" && ($("div.loadingplace").val() != ["London", "Manchester", "Liverpool"]  {
                    $("div.containersize").val("40' Container");
                }
         
            });
```

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: First of all you should else if to prevent execution of multiple conditions. It would also help if you could specify what error you get when you run the script

Comment: Please provide the HTML with the drop down values.

Comment: what is the issue now? Your `if` has a missing `)` also the part `$("div.loadingplace").val() != ["London", "Manchester", "Liverpool"]` is wrong it should be `["London", "Manchester", "Liverpool"].indexOf($("div.loadingplace").val()) == -1`

Comment: Will provide it in a bit thanks for your replies.

Comment: Will provide it in a bit thanks for your replies. I don't get any error it's just not working. I fixed the missing bracket as well. I'll update in a bit just testing a few things quickly.

Comment: So if the loading place is one of these three cities, which container size should be shown? You leave no possibility in the description...

Comment: If it's one of those three cities. both 20' container and 40' container must be shown. But that one I have found a way to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you use a library that provides `div` elements a drop-down behaviour, as in standard HTML `div` elements do not generate `change` events. So in the snippet below, I will use `select` elements instead.

Some issues in your code:

- To check if a string occurs in an array you cannot just compare with `!=`, but should use a method like `indexOf()`, or `includes()` in modern browsers;
- You should not only respond on changes made in the truck size selection, but also on the location selection, as this also could influence the resulting value for the container size;
- The check you do on the cities seems to be at the wrong place, since you write that these cities never use "small" or "medium". So you would need to make the city-check when those "small" or "medium" values are selected -- which indicates a violation to the rule;
- When one of those three cities is selected, you could force the truck size to be "heavy", as that seems to be the only allowed value in those cases (although the information in your question is contradictory in the **"it must also"** section);
- I guess you'd also want to make the container size drop-down read-only to avoid that the user overrides the automated logic.

```js
$('select.loadingplace,select.trucksize').change(function () {
    if ($('select.trucksize').val() == 'Heavy - 24 tons' || 
            ["London", "Manchester", "Liverpool"].indexOf($('select.loadingplace').val()) > -1) {
        $('select.containersize').val("40' Container");
        $('select.trucksize').val('Heavy - 24 tons');
    } else {
        $('select.containersize').val("20' Container");
    }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Loading Places: 
<select class="loadingplace">
<option value="Birmingham">Birmingham</option>
<option value="Leeds">Leeds</option>
<option value="Liverpool">Liverpool</option>
<option value="London">London</option>
<option value"Manchester">Manchester</option>
</select>
<br>
Truck Size: 
<select class="trucksize">
<option value="Small - 5 tons">Small - 5 tons</option>
<option value="Medium - 10 tons">Medium - 10 tons</option>
<option value="Heavy - 24 tons">Heavy - 24 tons</option>
</select>
<br>
Container Size: 
<select class="containersize" disabled>
<option value="20' Container">20' Container</option>
<option value="40' Container">40' Container</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed answer! I have learned a lot from it! I will be adding the ajax library to my html page. Thanks a lot I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can I ask a question? How would I give this function a name? Do I have to add it here: "$('select.loadingplace,select.trucksize').change(function TESTNAME ()"?

Comment: Indeed, that is where you would put it. Did you try it?

Comment: Thank you. I will be testing it now. For some reason the Form software I'm using (RS Form Pro) was giving me issues with it and I forgot to add the function name in the required field.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close to the solution, you only need to check if the `loadingplace` value is *contained* in the array.

So this line:

```
$("div.loadingplace").val() != ["London", "Manchester", "Liverpool"]
```

Should be written as:

```
$.inArray($("div.loadingplace").val(), ["London", "Manchester", "Liverpool"]) === -1
```

[$.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) is a function that searches for a specified value within an array and returns its index (or -1 if not found) — hence the need to check if the value is greater than -1 (`> -1`). In your case it's even easier as you want to check whether the value is NOT there, so you can do `=== -1`.

You also have a syntax error in that same line, you're just missing a closing bracket. This is not a silver-bullet answer but it should point you to the right direction.

Comment: right, in that case just invert the result with `!`, so it becomes `!$.inArray(...)`

Comment: @RajshekarReddy, that doesn't really matter, just add a !

Comment: Thanks for your help guys I will be testing it soon and will come with an update.

Comment: @Evochrome I know about that.. What about OP.. :)

Comment: One more question: Could I use the #id's as well? And is there a function such as "onkeyup" I will have to use here?

Comment: yes, you can use ids and also using the "onkeyup" event should be correct in your case

Comment: @simone - I think the change event would be better.

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid those confusing if statements

You’ve identified a problem where you cannot figure out how to get some complex if statements to work. The difficulty understanding the if statements is a problem with your *code*, not with *you.* These constructs are hard to write, and to maintain.

You want to stop relying on complex if statements as soon as you can, for the benefit of whoever is supporting this code in a year.

### An example without if statements

I dummied up an example of how you could do this without any if statements at all. (Not saying that every `if` statement is bad.)

In this example, the logic of what truck and container sizes are available where is contained in the one big `locations` object. See how it is easier to read than the if statements? Easier to read means fewer errors.

And take a moment to consider what will happen when you need to change the logic of what container sizes are available where. Won’t changing the values of this object be easier than changing the if statement logic?

```js
locations = {

 "London" : {        
  "Heavy":   ["40"] 
 },
 "Liverpool" : {        
  "Heavy":   ["20","40"] 
 },
 "Manchester": {
  "Small":  ["20","40"] ,
  "Medium":   ["20"] ,
  "Heavy":  ["40"] 
 },
 "Hull": {

  "Small": ["20","40"] ,
  "Medium":  ["20"] ,
  "Heavy":  ["40"] 

 },
 "Bristol": {
  "Small": ["20","40"] ,
  "Medium":  ["20"] ,
  "Heavy": ["40"]
 }
}
var containerLabels = {
 "20": "20&apos; Container",
 "40": "40&apos; Container"

}

$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".js-location").on("change", function(event) {
  var location = $(event.currentTarget).val();
  setTruckSizes(location);

  var truckSize = $(".js-truck").val();
  setContainerSizes(location, truckSize);
 });

 $(".js-truck").on("change", function(event) {

  var location = $(".js-location").val();
  var truckSize = $(".js-truck").val();
  setContainerSizes(location, truckSize);
 });
});

function setTruckSizes(location) {

  var truckSizesObject = locations[location];

  $(".js-truck").empty();

  for (truckSize in truckSizesObject) {

  var optionEl = createOptionElement(truckSize,truckSize);
  $(".js-truck").append( optionEl );
  };
}

function setContainerSizes(location, truckSize) {
 var containerSizesArray = locations[location][truckSize];

 $(".js-container").empty();

 for (var i=0; i<containerSizesArray.length;i++) {
  var container = containerSizesArray[i];

  var optionEl = createOptionElement(container, containerLabels[container]);
  $(".js-container").append( optionEl );
 }
}

function createOptionElement(value, label) {
 var opt = $("<option></option>");
 opt.val(value).html(label);
 return opt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 Location: <select class="js-location">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="London">London</option>
  <option value="Liverpool">Liverpool</option>
  <option value="Manchester">Manchester</option>  
  <option value="Hull">Hull</option>
  <option value="Bristol">Bristol</option>
 </select> 
 <br>
 Truck Size: <select class="js-truck">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="Small">Small</option>
  <option value="Medium">Medium</option> 
  <option value="Large">Large</option>
 </select>

 <br>
 Container Size:
 <select class="js-container"> 
  <option value="">-Select One</option>
  <option value="20">20&apos; Container</option>
  <option value="40">40&apos; Container</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this one also helped solve my issue! Appreciate the response. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too hard.

Ok so,

Three dropdowns -

1. Location
2. Truck Size
3. Container Size

Container size seems to be dependent on the location and truck size.

I'd like to abstract this away to a function - `getContainerSize` -

```
var currentLocation = $('#location').val();
var currentTruckSize = $('#truckSize').val();
// Check if its a unique city.
var isInUniqueCities = ["London", "Manchester", "Liverpool"].indexOf(currentLocation) !== -1; 
if (!isInUniqueCities && ['Small', 'Medium'].indexOf(currentTruckSize) === -1) {
  return '20 Container'
}

if (!isInUniqueCities && currentTruckSize === 'Large') {
  return '40 Container';
} 

// Handle other conditions, your question seems to be incomplete.
```

You should then call this function on the [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event of the location and truck size dropdown to ensure that things work properly.

Comment: This is the kind of solution I had in mind. Thanks will test soon and update as I proceed. Thanks a bunch.